# how can I merge this two image with python numpy and opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mask

I have two binary images. The first is like this:

[image]

and the last one is like this:

[image]

They dont have the same sized curve. I want to add the second one's two white zones contained in the black zone to the first one's black zone.

My code runs like this,but this a wrong answer:

[image]

The question is like this,and I want get the the finally image which I draw in picture with the **the** **final** **image**:

[image]

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: Post the code what you tried till now

Comment: Post the final image that you want to see as well. What is the problem with the one you are currently generating?

Comment: Are you looking for the floodfill algorithm? It's hard to tell unless you post the expected result (use MS Paint). What you have now is not adequate.

Comment: Next time ping the users that request updates.

Comment: You are still not showing any code, just a set of requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image,ImageDraw, ImageColor, ImageChops

# Load images
im1 = Image.open('im1.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('im2.jpg')

# Flood fill white edges of image 2 with black
seed  = (0, 0)
black = ImageColor.getrgb("black")
ImageDraw.floodfill(im2, seed, black, thresh=127)

# Now select lighter pixel of image1 and image2 at each pixel location and save it
result = ImageChops.lighter(im1, im2)
result.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If you prefer **OpenCV**, it might look like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import cv2

# Load images
im1 = cv2.imread('im1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im2 = cv2.imread('im2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Threshold, because JPEG is dodgy!
ret, im1 = cv2.threshold(im1, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret, im2 = cv2.threshold(im2, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Flood fill white edges of image 2 with black
h, w = im2.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(im2, mask, (0,0), 0)

# Now select lighter of image1 and image2 and save it
result = np.maximum(im1, im2)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this does not use opencv, nice.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I haven't seen anywhere that says I have to use **all** listed tags. The same functions are available in **OpenCV**, e.g. `cv::floodFill()` so the same algorithm can be implemented in a couple of lines of `OpenCV` code if OP wants that. It is already in Python as requested.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have added an **OpenCV** version.

Comment: @MadPhysicist My apologies - I didn't even see your answer until this moment! I think the children playing `Fortnite` soaked all my bandwidth for SO refreshes!!!

Comment: To anyone trying this code, note that the OP's images are different sizes so I had to centre-crop them to match.

Comment: That's why I made my 9x9 arrays to play with :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Cool, we are on the same page. I do apologise again.

Comment: No need. I rather like your answer actually.

Comment: @ Mark Setchell    --thanks a lot , I can achieve my task with the OPENCV code ,I understand the algorithm.     but in the first code with PIL which has an error.

Comment: @ Mark Setchell  ---the error is in here ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508440/typeerror-int-object-is-not-subscriptable, thanks a lot for this

Comment: @MaJun. Don't put a space between `@` and the name. The user won't be tagged if you do. Notice how I wrote your name here.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `img1` is your first array (larger solid blob) and `img2` is the second (smaller blob with holes),  you need a method to identify and remove the outer region of the second image. The [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm is a good candidate. It is implemented in opencv as [`cv2.floodFill`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill).

The easiest thing to do would be to fill the outer edge, then just add the results together:

```
mask = np.zeros((img2.shape[0] + 2, img2.shape[1] + 2), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(img2, mask, (0, 0), 0, 0)
result = img1 + img2
```

Here is a toy example that shows mini-images topologically equivalent to your originals:

```
img1 = np.full((9, 9), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
img1[1:-1, 1:-1] = 0
img2 = np.full((9, 9), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
img2[2:-2, 2:-2] = 0
img2[3, 3] = img2[5, 5] = 255
```

The images look like this:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.imshow(img1)
ax2.imshow(img2)
```

[image: start]

After the flood fill, the images look like this:

[image]

Adding the resulting images together looks like this:

[image]

Keep in mind that `floodFill` operates in-place, so you may want to make a copy of `img2` before going down this road.

Comment: fascinating ! it is great ,it is useful, thans a lot .