# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, opencv

when I run my PIL code ,it has this error:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw, ImageColor, ImageChops

# Load images
im1 = Image.open('im1.png')
im2 = Image.open('im2.png')


# Flood fill white edges of image 2 with black
seed  = (0, 0)
black = ImageColor.getrgb("black")
ImageDraw.floodfill(im2, seed, black, thresh=127)

# Now select lighter pixel of image1 and image2 at each pixel location and 
result = ImageChops.lighter(im1, im2)
result.save('result.png')
```

the error is in my image processing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Martin 
Ma\Desktop\test\36\light_3_global\close_open\gray\main.py", line 96, in <module>
ImageDraw.floodfill(im2, seed, black, thresh=127)
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 346, in floodfill
if _color_diff(value, background) <= thresh:
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 386, in _color_diff
return abs(rgb1[0]-rgb2[0]) +  abs(rgb1[1]-rgb2[1]) +  abs(rgb1[2]-rgb2[2])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501817/how-can-i-merge-this-two-image-with-python-numpy-and-opencv/52504053#52504053)

how can I solve it? thanks a lot !

Comment: Check your inputs...

Comment: I think you need to create an ImageDraw drawing context object. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw

Comment: Please do some minimal debugging. Copying code that was given to you in response to a question asked with absolutely minimal effort and asking people to fix it for you is not very cool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52504053/2988730

Comment: What arguments does `floodfill` require, and what did you feed it?  There appears to be a mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed image type without thinking about the consequences. JPEG and PNG are fundamentally different beasts, and you need to be aware of that:

- JPEG images are lossily saved, so your data will not generally be read back with the same values you wrote - this seems to shock everyone. They threshold an image so that all values above 127 go white and others go black and have a true binary image, they then save as JPEG and are amazed that on reloading, the image has 78 colours despite having thresholded it.
- JPEG images have all sorts of artefacts - chunky blocks of noise which will mess up your processing - especially if you look at saturation.
- PNG images are often palettised where each pixel stores an index into a 256-colour palette, rather than an RGB triplet. Most operations will fail on palettised images because you are comparing an index with an RGB colour triplet.
- PNG images are often greyscale - so there is only one channel and comparisons with RGB triplets will fail because the number of channels differs.

So, in answer to your question, I suspect your PNG image is palettised (especially likely when it only has 2 colours). You therefore need to convert it to RGB or maybe Luminance mode on opening:

```
im1 = Image.open('im1.png').convert('RGB')
```